# .NET6 Blazor Server Application Localization

Tags: localization, blazor

I would like to add language resources to my application based on the browser language preferences.

Blazor server application, .net6, c#

I will be using the syntax such as this on a razor page.  @localizer["helloworld"]
I expecting the localizer to know the language set in the browser and then use the appropriate resource file.

I am using ISO language codes for the resource files.  The app needs to support english and french, so I have resource.resx and resource.fr.resx

I have spent lots of time trying to get this to work.  The documentation seems so easy, yet I have had zero success.

The application will compile and run.  The default language of English is always coming up, regardless of the browser language setting.  My theory is either the browser language is not being detected, or the naming of the resource file is incorrect preventing the localizer from using it.

The first lesson is that where builder.Services.AddLocalization(); is declared in program.cs is important.  It will not function at all if in the wrong location (line)

Does anyone have any experience with this issue using .net6 and Blazor server app?

Thanks,
Marc.

Comment: Did you call `app.UseRequestLocalization`?

Comment: No.  Never noticed that in the documentation.  I assume this should go after  builder.Services.AddLocalization()?

Comment: Please read the [documentation located here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server).

Comment: thx.  I am going to give that a go.

Answer (score 2):

For a full example about localization.

https://github.com/iso8859/AspNetCoreAuthMultiLang

```
#region Localization
builder.Services.AddLocalization(option => option.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>()
                {
                    new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                    new CultureInfo("fr-FR")
                };
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US");
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
});
#endregion
```

#edit
Because server side blazor app are Single Page App you can't change the cookie. The only way to change a cookie it is to do a page refresh. This is done in the AuthController.cs

For WASM Project you can set cookie using Javascript
the value is for en-US

`Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Culture=c%3Den-US%7Cuic%3Den-US; path=/`

Comment: thx.  I am going to review that.

Comment: Remi.  I have the sample working, but do not need the authentication bits.  I have been trying to pull that out without luck.  Is the authentication necessary for this example to work>

Comment: No, it isn't. You have to set the cookie, look at Controllers/AuthController.cs and ApplyCulture method.

Answer (score 1):

Both the above posts provided the information I needed for my implementation.  Some of the MS documentation was a bit cryptic in assuming you knew all the correct parameter settings, but after a bit of tweaking I was successfully able to build the solution I required for my application.  Thanks to all for their help.