# Could not load file or assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0' in System.Resources.ResourceManager

Tags: c#, blazor, resourcemanager, mscorlib

I have a Blazor .NET6.0 project. I have developed a UI plugin system and a translate service (IStringLocalizer does not work inside the plugin).

Everything goes ok in debug mode and standalone release mode. But when I start it in docker-compose in release mode a 'Could not load file or assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0' exception is thrown. The exception is thorwn in this line:

resourceManager = new System.Resources.ResourceManager($"{Assembly}.{Class}.{Language}", _localizationAssembly);

I insist that in debug mode it works ok.

Comment: Are you debugging on windows and your container is linux?

Comment: Yes, container is linux, everything else is windows.

Comment: Then you should check if you referenced some .Net Framework assembly that can not be loaded under linux.

Comment: @DanielW. Debug containers are also Linux. It only fails in Release mode.

Comment: There's some backwards compatibility in .net6 to accommodate old code bases that still have a dependency on .net4.  Work on Windows, odds on Linux are much lower since mscorlib has very strong winapi dependencies.  You probably have to eliminate ResourceManager, notes on how to localize on .net6 [are here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72537507/net6-blazor-server-application-localization).

Comment: Can't manage to work with StringLocalizer inside the plugin, it compiles but does not translate. Tried with resources dll in every directory. Is there an alternative to ResourceManager?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally managed to get it to work with `ResourceReader`.

`ResourceManager` works okay inside a Blazor page (`OnInitilized`), but fails outside it. `ResourceReader` works fine.